# plugman not working on windows? adding core features to phonegap 3.0 app

Tags: plugins, cordova, command-line-interface

I have followed theese [instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins).

- installed plugman (command didnt work, so I added this C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules.bin to PATH to make 'plugman' command work in cmd).
- after getting plugman command to work (it's help was working in console), Ive entered the camera api command:

  plugman --platform android --project c:/path/to/app --plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git

the output was:

```
undefined is not a function
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer on phonegap google group.

To make this work, you need to install git console and then download the plugin with command:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

Answer (score 0):

The is a [bug that was recently submitted](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4375) and fixed.

You basically need Git installed, yes, but for plugman to work in "cmd.exe" (or any non-Git CLI) you need to have Git/bin in your system path.

Taken from my blog (http://atomicstructure.net/blog/2013/07/phonegap-3-0-troubles):

> Click **Start**, right-click **Computer** then select **Properties**. Click **Advanced System Settings** (top-left) then **Environment Variables** in the **Advanced** tab.
>
> Under **System variables** find the variable called **Path** and edit that to include the *full system path to where Git is installed*. So for example, mine now reads:
>
> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%; [snip] **;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin**
>
> With the all important bit highlighted in bold. As with Ant and Android Development Tools, *you'll need to include the /bin subfolder*, too.